# Is there any such component (for displaying expandable lists)?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to render an expandable list which initially displays around 6-8 items list but on clicking `'Show all'` it should show the entire items list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No PrimeFaces component comes to mind, but how about just this?

```xml
<h:form>
    <ul>
        <ui:repeat value="#{bean.list}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
            <ui:fragment rendered="#{loop.index lt 6 or bean.showAll}">
                <li>#{item}</li>
            </ui:fragment>
        </ui:repeat>
    </ul>
    <h:commandButton value="Show all" action="#{bean.setShowAll(true)}" rendered="#{!bean.showAll}">
        <f:ajax render="@form" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

with

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten");
    private boolean showAll;

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public boolean isShowAll() {
        return showAll;
    }

    public void setShowAll(boolean showAll) {
        this.showAll = showAll;
    }

}
```

You could wrap it if necessary in a composite.

Comment: could you enlighten me why do we need `implements Serializable` ? I never used to do this. Is it a good practice to include this ?

Comment: For view and session scoped beans, yes. On some servers the HTTP session may be saved on disk (e.g. to save sessions before restart so that they can be revived thereafter) or transferred over network (e.g. for clustering). Normally, Mojarra would show warnings in logs whenever the view/session scoped bean is not serializable.